# How can convert character "%xx" in html using Perl

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, uri

I intended to extract content from a web page which contains many unicode characters represented in the form of "%xx". As I used Perl module LWP to get web page, naturally handled these unicode characters using Perl Regex as below.

```
my $html = "%20%26%40 ";
$html =~ s#%([0-9a-f]+)#\x{\1}#ig;
print "$html\n";
```

But above code dosen't work， it output nothing but "00". Get stuck now ...
Any hint would be appreciated.

Thanks, Ye

Comment: It's URI-encoding, not Unicode.

Comment: Are you sure `[0-9a-f]+` is the right expression to use? URI-encoding will always have 2 hex digits per token. So `%2012` should be rendered as `" 12"`, not as `\x{2012}`.

Comment: Right, added tag URI just now.

Answer (score 8):

Perl has functions built in the [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape) module for this already. You don't need to mess with regular expressions

```
use URI::Escape;
my $encode = uri_unescape($string);
```

See [this page](http://www.perlhowto.com/encode_and_decode_url_strings) for more

Comment: -1. I don't see when this would be useful. You need to parse the url before you can use `uri_unescape` on the components -- you can't use `uri_unescape` on the url as a whole -- and the URL parser should unescape the components for you. The OP is clearly not writing a URL parser (since he thinks he's dealing with HTML), so your advice will give incorrect results.

Answer (score 2):

You need an executable substitution

```
$html =~ s/%([0-9a-f]+)/chr hex $1/ieg;
```

but it is better to use the [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape) module, which is part of Gisle Aas' excellent LWP suite

Answer (score 0):

First, that has nothing to do with HTML. That escaping mechanism is used by URI.

It seems really odd that you would have to do that. The only thing that usually needs to undo that encoding is CGI scripts receiving parameters, in which case all you need is

```
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new();
my $foo = $cgi->param('foo');
```

But let's say you need to do your own URI parsing. You could use:

```
use URI;
my %form = URI->new($url)->query_form();
my $foo = $form{'foo'};
```

[CGI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI), [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?URI)

Answer (score -1):

Funny and ugly code :

```
my $html = "%20%26%40 ";
$html =~ s#%([0-9a-f]{2})#"chr(0x$1)"#igee;
print "$html\n";
```

Edit : (I'm obliged to say) this code is maybe *cute*, but **do not** use this in production ! (there are many cases where it's not working)

Comment: Less ugly and more canonical: `s#...#chr hex $1#ige`

Comment: Yes, but I could not resist to this occasion to use a `/ee` regexp attribute :p

Comment: Anyway, they can both work. Firstly make code workable then make code beautiful:-) Thanks.

Comment: But never be tempted to use a hack because it's cute. Any `s///ee` substitution is a desperate last-resort. Even `s///e` should be used sparingly

Comment: Real coders will send us burn in hell for that, but life is short :)

Comment: @Orabîg: please don't encourage bad practice here

Comment: @Bordin Thanks for your reminding.  I have checked the manual of Perlre. It said " However, if you get into the habit of doing that, you get yourself into trouble if you then add an /e modifier."